# Most common character in a file in C

Tags: c, file, character

I'm doing my C programming course homework and I need to find a most common character in given file.

My testing with a testfile, emptyfile and other small amount text files works great (or at least I think so), but in the last long testfile something goes wrong and the error message is: **"Should have returned 'e' (101) for file rfc791.txt. You returned 'b' (98)"**.

So what I'm asking that what might be wrong with my code, when suddenly the most common letter is not what is should be?

```
int most_common_character(char *filename) {
    FILE *f;
    if ((f = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not opened: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    char frequency[26];
    int ch = fgetc(f);
    if (ch == EOF) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (ch = 0; ch < 26; ch++) {
        frequency[ch] = 0;
    }

    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if (ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {
            frequency[ch - 'a']++;
        }
        else if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {
            frequency[ch - 'A']++;
        }
    }
    int maxCount = 0;
    int maxChar = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 26; ++i) {
        if (frequency[i] > maxCount) {
            maxCount = frequency[i];
            maxChar = i;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return maxChar + 'a';
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone has any hints to fix my code :) I've tried to search the solution to this problem from many other related topics but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 26; ++i)` breaks the array bounds.

Comment: I would also not use a `char` array, it won't work on larger files. Use `unsigned int`.

Comment: Moreover you are reading and discarding the first character in the file.

Comment: well, @WeatherVane gave you the answer. `char` range is not enough for your test file.

Comment: Thank you Weather Vane! Seems to be that fixing the char to unsigned int and changing  i <= 26; to i< 26; solved my problem. :D Thank you!

Comment: `int ch = fgetc(f);` drop one character.

Answer (score 0):

You should use < operator in the second for loop. Because of that when you are checking frequency[i] > maxCount, at frequency[26] it behaves undefined behaviour, meaning the value at that index may be less or higher than the compared value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code do have some problems. However, they are so tiny so the code still works well with small tests.

1. `int ch = fgetc(f);` drop the first char in the file
2. `for (int i = 0; i <= 26; ++i)` break out of the array 's range (only from 0-->25)

**Beside these small mistakes, your code is awesomely fine. Well done #thumbsup**

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop runs out-of-bounds.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743770/most-common-character-in-a-file-in-c#comment66784398_39743770)

   ```
   // for (int i = 0; i <= 26; ++i) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
   ```
2. Code throws away result of the first character. [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743770/most-common-character-in-a-file-in-c#comment66784948_39743770)

   ```
   int ch = fgetc(f);
   if (ch == EOF) {
     return 0;
   }
   // This value of ch is not subsequently used.
   ```

Other fixes as below

```
int most_common_character(char *filename) {
    ...

    // Use a more generous count @Weather Vane
    // char frequency[26];
    // Consider there may be more than 26 different letters
    // fgetc return EOF and value in the unsigned char range
    int frequency[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 0 };

    // Not needed as array was initialize above
    // for (ch = 0; ch < 26; ch++) { frequency[ch] = 0; }

    // BTW correct type declaration of int, avoided rookie mistake of using char
    int ch;

    // Codes use tolower(), islower() as that is the portable way to 
    // handle type-of-character detection
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
      frequency[tolower(ch)]++;  // could add check to insure frequency[] does not overflow
    } 

    int maxCount = 0;
    int maxChar = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= UCHAR_MAX; ++i) {
      if (islower(i) && frequency[i] > maxCount) {
        maxCount = frequency[i];
        maxChar = i;
      }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return maxChar;
}
```